# Error when integrating django channels with existing django 3.1 wsgi code

Tags: python, django, django-channels, django-3.1

I am getting the following error when adding channels in Django.

Exception inside application: **init**() takes 1 positional argument When adding ASGI_APPLICATION in Django 3.1 for channels

```
Exception inside application: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dell/Desktop/s/s/s-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/dell/Desktop/s/s/s-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/dell/Desktop/s/s/s-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 160, in __call__
    send,
  File "/home/dell/Desktop/s/s/s-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/compatibility.py", line 33, in new_application
    instance = application(scope)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were give
```

The application works fine on WSGI configuration.The above error only appears when `ASGI_APPLICATION = 'app.routing.application'` is added.

Since it's showing error originating from static files, I have tried generating static files again but that doesn't help.

I am using default django asgi file:

```
"""
ASGI config for mevsyou project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 's.settings.local')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

*s/routing.py:*

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from users import routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': URLRouter(routing.urlpatterns),
})
```

Comment: You need to define a constructor `__init__` for `application` with two parameters: `__init__(self, scope)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Where? I have default django asgi.py file

Comment: not the `asgi` file, the `app.routing.application`.

Comment: If you want to support both you can do `__init__(self, *args)` or `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` if you want to be as generic as possible

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added routing.py code

Comment: @NadeemDouba Where?

Comment: Which version of django-channels?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is for Channels 2, while you're using Channels 3.

In Channels 3, you should not have `routing.py`. But your `asgi.py` file should look like this:

```py
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
})
```

As a matter of fact, `ASGI_APPLICATION` should be set to `'app.asgi.application'`.

[See Channels docs for 3.x](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/installation.html)

Comment: I have version 3.

Comment: So, that's the problem. Your code is for Channels 2. If you use version 3, make sure to follow docs for Channels 3.